# Replacing if validations with a better error handling

Tags: javascript

I have this little piece of front-end code, and I had a little code smell about the handling of errors.

```
  request
   .post(('/api/comment/:id/upvote').replace(':id', this.comment.id))
      .end(function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        log('Fetch error: %s', err);
        return classes(targetElement).remove('selected');
      }

      if (res.status == 401) {
        return errorContainer.innerHTML = t(res.body.error);
      }

      if (!res.ok) {
        log('Fetch error: %s', res.error);
        return classes(targetElement).remove('selected');
      }

      if (res.body && res.body.error) {
        log('Fetch response error: %s', res.body.error);
        return classes(targetElement).remove('selected');
      }

      log('successfull upvote %s', self.comment.id);
      });
```

In all error conditions, I should "rollback" an status of html element.

```
classes(targetElement).remove('selected');
```

I can chain all conditions in one `if` in order to handle errors, but there's still a code smell.

Does someone have some ideas on how to wrap this in a better error handling?

Comment: Depending on what the API returns you might be able to go with `var error = err || res.error || res.body.error;`

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you have two things going on: detecting the error, and reporting the error.  You have a *lot* of different error handling; is there a way to abstract this down into a message?  Maybe a pair of functions, one of which abstract all of these errors down to a single, page-side error code, and the other of which presents a textual version of that.  Or something that returns a tuple.

In the meantime, I've broken it down into "something went wrong" and "what kind of wrongness happened" blocks.

The one thing that stands out at me is you have two different return types: whatever is returned from the function classes(), and the `undefined` at the end of the function on success.  By putting the error handler's `return` on its own line, I've made sure that js-hint and js-lint won't complain about inconsistent return types.

```
(function (err, res) {
    if ((err) || (res.status == 401) || (!res.ok) || (res.body && res.body.error)) {
        classes(targetElement).remove('selected');
        if (err || (res.body && res.body.error) || (!res.ok)) {
            log("Fetch error: ", (err || res.error || (res.body && res.body.error)));
        }
        if (res.status == 401) {
            errorContainer.innerHTML = t(res.body.error);
        }
        return;
    }
    log('successfull upvote %s', self.comment.id);
});
```

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but the line with
 
`log("Fetch error: ", (err || res.error || (res.body && res.body.error)));`

returns `Fetch error: true/false`

Comment: Also i think in a similar solution, but I have the same problem, in few lines.

Comment: The || function in this context will return the content of the first value that does not evaluate to falsy (false, 0, null, undefined, "").  So if err is undefined but res.error has text, the text will be the first 'or' clause that evaluates to non-false, the text will be the value of the total expression.

Comment: Sorry, I miss the begining of `()`